# How to EVAL a SELECT String and EXECUTE

Tags: sql, foreach, eval, informix, execute

I wrote a function, *StoogeFunk*, that uses FOREACH against *systables* and *syscolumns*, to concatenate in a string the list of fields in a table (the name of which is passed as a function parameter). I surround with CAST/VARCHAR(30) the date fields, for reasons I dare not explain. So, I come to a point where I have in a string, *SelectString*, the equivalent of:

```
SELECT Name, CAST(DOB AS VARCHAR(30)) AS DOB, ShoeSize FROM Stooges
```

My function simply returns that LVARCHAR string (and it is a long one, due to many fields). That result-text SELECT works fine in a query window.

1.) Now, instead of returning that string (a simple "RETURN SelectString;" line before "END FUNCTION;"), I want to execute the string, returning from the function a nice, big, juicy bunch of records. I imagine something like an EVAL:

```
RETURN EVAL(SelectString);
```

How may I reach that dream?

2.) If the above is impossible, could I call the *SelectString*-result function externally?

```
EXECUTE EVAL(StoogeFunk("StoogeTable"))
```

How would that be workable?

Comment: The difficulty with executing the string in a function is that the return type of the function has to be known when it is compiled. If you pass different table names to your function, in general you'll have different types to be returned. You might finesse the issue by returning the data in each row as a JSON (or BSON) document. Or you might return all the rows as a bigger JSON (or BSON) document. Returning multiple rows isn't a problem; you simply return the value WITH RESUME. Modern versions of Informix support dynamic SQL in functions, but the return type is still probably the show-stopper.

Comment: So, JSON/BSON aside (no idea how to do that), it sounds like I cannot have a generic procedure that produces and executes a customized SELECT statement on-the-fly for a given table name, because the procedure has to know at compile time the data type of each field of a returned row (and the number of fields and their data types will, of course, vary by table).

Still, I have my function's composed SELECT statement returned as a string.  How may I then write that SELECT string as a new view and then call the view (and I don't mean those too-chatty women on ABC)?

Comment: More or less. Unless the return type from the generic procedure is the 'same' for all possible queries, you can't do it. That's where JSON or BSON might come into play — you store the row of data in one of those two formats and return a single value.  You could use the dynamic SQL facilities in modern SPL to take the string and make a view out of it.  You'd still have to write some code somewhere to read the values from the view, though.

Comment: Mr. Leffler, thank you for your kind and prompt help!  What you said about the definitions needing to be in place at compile time for the function made sense, as did going the longer route via JSON/BSON strings.  I managed to figure out a solution:  Write a procedure in which SelectString is built, as above, and embed that into a second string, ViewString, which does a CREATE VIEW.  Then, as the last line of the procedure:  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ViewString.  --CONTINUED IN COMMENT BELOW --

Comment: --CONTINUED FROM COMMENT ABOVE --  Finally, call the view outside of the procedure:  This eliminates Informix's tedious requirement to define and enumerate in the procedure all of the fields and data types to be returned (redundant, as all of that is already listed in the view).

Comment: That should work OK. CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS may be of use to you.  When I'm going to continue a comment, I use _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ and continue like this.  Slightly less emphatic (less shouting) than all caps.  Sometimes, I don't put the continuation comments in — but I don't normally break mid-sentence (I did here, but that's a very special case).